# Coherence vs. Magnitude Squared Coherence

Tags: time-series, spectral-analysis

Currently I am writing my master thesis. The theory part is about the turbulent wind field generation, where the coherence (not magnitude squared) is used:

$$\text{coh}(f) = \frac{|P_{xy}|}{\sqrt{P_{xx} P_{yy}}}$$

I am wondering what is the general advantage of using the magnitude squared coherence instead:

$$\text{coh}^2(f) = \frac{|P_{xy}|^2}{P_{xx} P_{yy}}$$

I think this relationship is similar to that of the correlation coefficient $R$ and coefficient of determination $R^2$. I tried to google the difference regarding the coherence, but unfortunately I don't find any (good) explanations.

Comment: And I just saw that there were some typing errors in my equations. The relationship between both equations is the square root, as in $R$ and $R^2$, but I do not see the advantage of using the squared version.